# Why does NASA's B-52 008 have a smoking engine in this photograph?

Tags: jet-engine, nasa

This is a photograph from the launch of an [X-43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43) from the NASA owned and operated [B-52 '008'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress). It appears that one engine is producing a plume of smoke in the photograph. Why is this?

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43)</sup>

Comment: That's what you get when there is no cabin attendant to tell the crew this is non-smoking flight.

Comment: @RobVermeulen She was commissioned in 1959... everyone smoked back then ;)

Comment: @RobVermeulen Ladies and gentleman this is your captain speaking - I've just turned off the "No Smoking" signs. I figure if the plane's smoking why can't you? (Also can we talk about the soot marks behind those engine pods? *Wash your planes, NASA!*)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

@Adam is right. The aircraft, [NB-52B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_8) has [smoke generator installed to assist in tracking](http://www.air-and-space.com/20001102%20NB-52B%20X-38.htm).

> A smoke generator has been installed on the left wing of the Boeing NB-52B Stratofortress mothership to assist in tracking the airplane.

Its use during the test of X-38 is [detailed here](http://www.air-and-space.com/20010710%20NB-52%20X-38.htm):

> Outside I could see the white trail from the smoke generator in the number-2 engine nacelle of the NB-52B approaching from the east
>
> ... I aimed my telephoto nearly directly up at the tip of the smoke trail.

As the same aircraft [was used during the X-43 tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43), it certainly served the same purpose.

Comment: So, paratroopers invented jumping out of a perfectly good airplane. Not to be one-upped, NASA decided to set a perfectly good plane on fire. Touche :)

Answer (score 31):

My guess, and it is only a guess, is that they are using a smoke generator to make the B-52 aircraft easier to visualize.  Typically for flight tests like this they would be doing optical tracking from the ground (essentially a telescope) and this would make it easier to locate the target.  (I was going to add also for the pilot of the dropped aircraft, but the X-43 is unmanned)